# Email confirmation using Fortify Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-fortify

I am using Fortify without Jetstream for authentication. I read in the documentation about email verifycation at the time of registration. But what about confirmation the email address when the user changes the email address? Is it difficult to implement using this package or does it not have a ready-made functionality for this, and I have to do it from scratch?

In user pannel it's possible to change username, email, phone and img(I will add it later):

```
public function user_update(Request $request){

      $user = Auth::user();

      $user->name = $request->input('name')?$request->input('name'):Auth::user()->name;
      $user->email = $request->input('email')?$request->input('email'):Auth::user()->email;
      $user->phone = $request->input('phone')?$request->input('phone'):(Auth::user()->phone?Auth::user()->phone:NULL);

      $user->update();

      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/user-panel/user-update', [AdminController::class, 'user_update'])->name('user_update');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable the `Features::emailVerification()` feature in the `fortify.php` config file you get access to the `verified` middleware which confirms that a `user` has verified their email by asserting the `email_verified_at` field in the database for that `user` is not null.

So to trigger a requirement for a `user` to verify a new email if they change theirs, what you want to do is change the value of the `email_verified_at` field to `null` if the `user` alters their email address.

You **could** write out this logic yourself, however, Fortify actually provides this out of the box. In the `app/Actions/Fortify` folder you'll see a file named `UpdateUserProfileInformation.php` which does exactly what you require and implements the entire email verification workflow including generating a new verification email to the `user`.

You may need to alter this slightly for any changes you have made to the structure of the default `user`.

Thereafter, all you will need to do in order to use this is configure your `<form>` appropriately.

```
<form action="{{ route('user-profile-information.update') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method("PUT")
</form>
```

You could use the `url` if you don't like named routes, but the end result would be the same.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! It is strange that if this functionality comes `out of the box`, why is there no information about it either in the documentation or on the Internet. Although maybe I was looking badly) Or this functionality is not particularly in demand.

Comment: @Hi_TecH Fortify is relatively new and unfortunately its official docs are a little lacking but improving. The [`Jetstream docs`](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/profile-management.html#actions) (Jetstream uses Fortify) are better but don't always go into great detail. I found [this Fortify series](https://codecourse.com/watch/authentication-with-laravel-fortify) very helpful, or some free alternatives [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxFwlLOncxFLxT3ZxYPw7-hCrXhdZHg1W) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxFwlLOncxFIbxi2gQCN3SR5e3-WB-4T2).